# Converting PyGTK Script to EXE results in old Windows 2K GUI Look

Tags: python, windows, gtk, pygtk, py2exe

My application gets the old Windows style/look when I compile my PyGTK Application into an .exe.

**How I can I preserve the Windows XP GUI look and style when I compile my Python/PyGTK script with Py2Exe or PyInstaller?**

Is there a special .dll I need to include, do I need to create my own .manifest file and link it in my Py2Exe script(if so how)? In Native WinAPI I can toggle Windows XP style by using the function InitCommonControls();, is there a PyGTK equivalent function that I can use?

Note: If I run my PyGTK script in the python interpreter then the GUI has the correct Windows XP modern look. But when I compile that same script into an .exe using Py2Exe or PyInstaller, the GUI of the .exe has the old Windows 2K look and not the modern Windows XP look.

*Any ideas on what I need to do to preserve the Windows XP look?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your are using:

```
'bundle_files': 3
```

and copy the GTK+ directories into the *dist* folder (i.e. etc, share, lib).

Comment: I could kiss you! :D I've been trying to figure this out for ages. Works perfectly. Thanks you

Comment: Exactly which directories, the ones in the Python27/Libs directory?, also they should be copied in the setup.py file or manually?